Class is ignoring values assigned in __init__ when instance created
I am trying to create some buttons with Discord.Py where the labels change. I've created a discord.ui.View and then inside that I have an __init__ which accepts a name and id value. When I call the class, and add a break point on that I can see that the values are assigned to self.modelName and self.modelId, however, the button generated completely ignores these values, and uses the default values.
My class is defined as the following:
class AlphaStrikeCardButtons(discord.ui.View):
    modelName = "supernova 2"
    modelId = "3133"

    #defining constructor  
    def __init__(self,name,id):  
        super().__init__()
        self.modelName = name
        self.modelId = f'asc{id}'
        
    @discord.ui.button(label=modelName, custom_id=modelId, style=discord.ButtonStyle.blurple)
    #@discord.ui.button(label='supernova 5', custom_id='asc8132', style=discord.ButtonStyle.blurple)
    async def alphaStrikeCard(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.Button):
        cardPath = f'./tmp/asc{modelId}.png' #If it already exists, we don't need to download it again
        if os.path.isfile(cardPath) == False:
            cardUrl = f'http://masterunitlist.info/Unit/Card/{self.modelId}'
            print(cardUrl)
            urlretrieve(cardUrl,cardPath)
        cardFile = discord.File(cardPath,filename=f'{self.modelId}.png')
        await interaction.response.send_message(file=cardFile, ephemeral=False)
        self.stop()

Then then I call the class using:
ASCB = AlphaStrikeCardButtons(name=modelName,id=modelId)
await interaction.response.send_message("Please click the button:",ephemeral=True,view=ASCB)

The values of modelName and modelId in are 'Supernova 5' and '8132', however, the button prompted displayed "Supernova 2" and has a custom_id of asc3133, which is the default values. I confirmed the values are assigned by adding a breakpoint and hovering over the variable:

You can clearly see that self.modelName has the value Supernova 5; so it was correctly assigned.
If I don't assign values (assign None) to modelName and modelId at the start then when I call the class I get an even more confusing error:

In data.components.0.components.0.label: This field is required

So it's saying I'm not even passing the value, but I most certainly am.
Why is Python ignoring the values set to the variables modelName and modelId when I've confirmed that the values are being assigned and how do I ensure Python uses the passed values?

These are class variables:
class AlphaStrikeCardButtons(discord.ui.View):
    modelName = "supernova 2"
    modelId = "3133"

and these are instance variables:
class AlphaStrikeCardButtons(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self, name, id):
        self.modelName = name
        self.modelId = f'asc{id}'

You are defining instance and class variables with the same name, which doesn't seem to be your intention.
The arguments you provide (label=modelName, custom_id=modelId) to your button decorator (@discord.ui.button) are referring to the class variables, which explains the behavior and why you get an error if you remove them.
Note you cannot simply put self. in front of these arguments. Since a decorator is just syntactic sugar around a function, you cannot reference self in arguments supplied to it as the object referenced by self doesn't exist at the time of function definition.
I'm not familiar with the discordpy library, but it looks like you can use the Button constructor to initialize it with the values you want and then attach it to your component, rather than using the decorator -  documentation
Edit: this poster seemed to be trying to do something similar; check out the comments of the answer

Ok that explains the why, however you say I also can't use self., so how do I pass those values?

OK, this ended up going in the direction of an XY Problem; this put me on the right direction though. I might take the time to post a self answered question (for the X), if I don't find a duplicate question out there.

I'm not familiar with this library so I'm only referring to the documentation... instead of using the @discord.ui.button decorator, instantiate a button using my_button = discord.ui.Button(label=modelName, custom_id=modelId) and then attach it to your component

@Mogo brilliant link! :) I would bet there's more than one way to accomplish what you are wanting

"You should not have instance and class variables with the same name" you can if you understand what that means and that is what you want.

@juanpa.arrivillaga thanks for pointing that out, I've adjusted the language as to not mislead future visitors
